# How to make GNU make command recognized anywhere

Tags: windows, gnu-make

I installed GNU-make. I added it to PATH.
However, it's recognized only in its path.
I mean, when I write: C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin>make
It works and gives me this response:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
But, when I write: C:>make
It says, make isn't recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: Then you did *not* properly update your `PATH`. What did you  change it to?

Comment: No,  I just needed to restart my device.

Answer (score 0):

It's now solved. 
It was all about restarting my device